# How to configure the gitkit cookie

Tags: java, google-identity-toolkit

Is there a way to configure parameters of the gitkit cookie?

Specifically I want to specify domain and path. I am using java.

Looking at source of www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js there is a "cookiePolicy" but no documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend.

The reason I would like to configure this is to use the same gtoken (gitkit) cookie from different sub domains. But maybe this can be set form the Google Cloud Console (Browser API key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitkit now supports custom cookie policies. The official documentation hasn't been updated yet but this is basically how it works:

There are 3 policies:

- Single Host Origin: Single host name with no subdomains will be enforced. This is the default option when not provided. It is also the policy that the current client uses.So only the current domain and its root path and not its subdomains will be used. So if the cookie is set on page http://example.com, only that domain can read that cookie. http://www.example.com will not be able to read the cookie.
- None: no gtoken cookie saved.
- Uri: In this case a uri is provided, eg: https://b.c.com/path/to/cookie/root/ and it will be used to determine the following cookie properties: 
  Secure: This is determined from the protocol. It only accepts https or both https/http. Any other scheme will issue an error. This field will be true when https is set.
  Domain: In this case the domain would be set to .b.c.com.
  Path: If not provided the path would be set to ‘/’, otherwise it will set to ‘/path/to/cookie/root/’ in the example below.

To use:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  signInSuccessUrl: '/main',
  oobActionUrl: '/email',
  signInOptions: ['google', 'facebook', 'password'],
  cookiePolicy: 'https://b.c.com/path/to/cookie/root/'
  // cookiePolicy: 'none'
  // cookiePolicy: 'single_host_origin'
};
window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
  '#gitkitWidgetDiv',
  config,
  '');
```